# Extrair dados no JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

estou tendo um problema com Ajax... Não estou conseguindo extrair os dados. Eles são retornados, porém, na hora de imprimir, nada aparece.
Segue códigos:
Model:

```
function livros() {
        $this->db->select('idobras,titulo,idbib_exemplares,bib_obras_idobras');
        $this->db->from('bib_exemplares');
        $this->db->join('bib_obras', 'idobras = bib_obras_idobras');
        $this->db->where('estado','Ativo');
        $this->db->order_by('titulo','asc');
        $result = $this->db->get();

        if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
            return  $result->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
function GetLivros() {
        $book = $this->bib_movimentacao_model->livros();
        if ($book) {
            echo json_encode($book);
        }else{
            echo json_encode('');
        }
    }
```

Trecho do JQuery:

```
print = '<div id="rem">'+
    '<blockquote>'+
        '<div class="form-inline">'+
            '<label>Livro:&nbsp;</label>';

            $.ajax({
                'url': 'bib_movimentacao_controller/GetLivros',
                'type': 'POST',
                'data': {

                 },
                'success': function(data){
                    var result = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(data);
                    print += '<select name="livros[]" id="livros" class="form-control" data-live-search="true" style="width: 80%">';
                        $.each(result, function(index, val){
                            print += '<option value="'+val.idbib_exemplares+'">'+val.titulo+'</option>';
                        });
                    print += '</select>';
                }
            });

print += '</div>'+
```

Nesse alert, vi que os dados estão sendo trazidos corretamente.
  Desde já agradeço a ajuda, pessoal.
P.S: Segue img de como fica:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A operação de ajax é feito de forma assíncrona, ou seja, ele só está concatenando aquele texto na variável quando a requisição for retornada. Mova a variável print e o restante do código para dentro do success e o problema será resolvido.

Comment: Muito obrigada pela ajuda, Gabriel! Deu certo!! \Ooo/